# Create a list from a range of values in cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, range

Can someone help me with this ?
I would like excel to create a list depending on a range:

```
Range1: B1: 1 C1:5
Range2: B2: 10 C2: 15
```

I `Column A4` and below `:1,2,3,4,5,10,11,12,13,14,15`
Range input will vary so Range can change but at max `1-255`

I have tried `IF` command but its getting too complicated

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share a screenshot of your data? (someone will edit it into your post if you post a link)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Formula:
`=IF(ROW(B1)>$C$1,IF(ROW(B1)+($B$2-$C$1-1)>$C$2,"",ROW(B1)+($B$2-$C$1-1)),ROW(B1))`

Keep $ sign for Absolute Reference, it will remain fix when you drag the formula down
Just write it in A4 and drag it down till it becomes empty
You can change the values in B1, C1 or B2, C2 it will still work